# ranking the rows in sql

Tags: group-by

What I want to do is to understand the order per location. Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

```
class   grade   location rank
A       21       G         3
A       22       H         2
A       23       F         1
B       27       G         1
B       25       H         2
B       24       F         3
C       22       G         3
C       28       H         2
C       29       F         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `rank()`:

```
select t.*, rank() over (partition by year order by grade desc) as seqnum
from t;
```